# Php Server Side Caching

Tags: php, caching, server-side

I've started using server-side caching which is really important.

I'm simply calling `ob_start()` at the beginning of the file and `ob_get_contents()` at the end to write the page as an html file.

This far there's no problem but i want to be more specific about what to cache because not everything on a page is static . Is there any standard of server-side caching?
I'm sure i can accomplish this by writing necessary things to a file and reading from it when necessary. I'm just wondering if there's any standards of doing it.

Comment: There are lots of different ways you might approach this, each with its own advantages and disadvantages. What is best will depend on your application.

Comment: Also, output buffering is not at all related to caching.

Comment: Can't I use it as a form of caching? It just runs query the first time website is visited then saves whole output as html. What you mean is caching to ram maybe?